# make d3 line graph responsive

Tags: javascript, d3.js, responsive-design

I have the following d3 line chart, and while I am aware of [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/17/building-responsible-visualizations-d3-js/) tutorial on how to make a line chart responsive, I am having trouble applying it to my existing graph...

Essentially, I would like the chart to fill the browser window width and height 100%, and resize with the window. I'm sure my graph code itself is abysmal, so any pointers on cleaning it up would also be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// set dimensions of the graph

var margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// parse the date format
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

//colors (this is new)
// Our color bands
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#308fef", "#5fa9f3", "#1176db"]);


// set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
     var simple_pre_ingest_staging_data = <?php echo $simple_pre_ingest_staging_data; ?>;
     var simple_backlog_data = <?php echo $simple_backlog_data; ?>;
     var simple_ready_data = <?php echo $simple_ready_data; ?>;

    //get data for pre-ingest
    simple_pre_ingest_staging_data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });



    //get data for readyForIngest_data
    simple_ready_data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });


    //get data for artworkBacklog_data
    simple_backlog_data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });



    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(simple_pre_ingest_staging_data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, 800]);



    // draw pre-ingest
    svg.append("path")  
        .attr("class", "pre_ingest")
        .attr("d", valueline(simple_pre_ingest_staging_data))
        .attr("data-legend",function(d) { return "Pre-ingest Staging"});

    // draw simple_ready_data
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "readyForIngest")
        .attr("d", valueline(simple_ready_data))
        .attr("data-legend",function(d) { return "Ready for ingest"});

    // draw artworkBacklog_data
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "artworkBacklog")
        .attr("d", valueline(simple_backlog_data))
        .attr("data-legend",function(d) { return "Artwork level backlog"});



    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
  legend = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class","legend")
    .attr("transform","translate(850,30)")
    .style("font-size","12px")
    .call(d3.legend)

  setTimeout(function() { 
    legend
      .style("font-size","20px")
      .attr("data-style-padding",10)
      .call(d3.legend)
  },1000)

svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "x label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("x", width)
    .attr("y", height - 6)
    .text("date");
    svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "y label")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".75em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .text("number of artworks");

svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", (width / 2))             
        .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
        .style("font-size", "16px") 
        .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
        .text("Number of Artworks in ingest queue");

</script>
```

Comment: Telling us what `var simple_pre_ingest_staging_data = <?php echo $simple_pre_ingest_staging_data; ?>;
     var simple_backlog_data = <?php echo $simple_backlog_data; ?>;
     var simple_ready_data = <?php echo $simple_ready_data; ?>;` actually resolve to would make this question a lot easier to answer.

Comment: A whole bunch of JSON https://gist.github.com/finoradin/d2ede5d3203af9ba191f